# Help With Sinusoidal Equation

Tags: trigonometry, graphing-functions

How do I find the equtation for the Sinusoidal Equation in BLUE?

[image: sinusoidals]

Comment: Hi, @Suz and welcome to Mathematics Stack exchange. Take a [tour](http://math.stackexchange.com/tour) to the site and read some questions/answers before posting. These things will help you in understanding the site in a better way.

Comment: @THELONEWOLF. I have edited Suz' question to include her graph which did not properly link.

Comment: Yes I see @JohnWaylandBales, our helpful behaviour towards each other is key to strengthen the community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a choice of using either sine or cosine, both of which are sinusoidal graphs.

The basic equation of an untranslated sine graph in terms of its amplitude $A$ and period $p$ is

$$ y=A\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{p}x\right)$$

But if it is translated horizontally by $h$ units and vertically by $k$ units the translated equation becomes

$$ y-k=A\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{p}(x-h)\right)$$

which us usually written in the form

$$ y=A\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{p}(x-h)\right)+k\tag{1}$$

To obtain the equation by visual inspection of a sinusoidal graph one must estimate the values of the amplitude and period and the amount of vertical or horizontal translation.

The amplitude is half the vertical distance between the peaks and troughs so we can conclude that $A=1$. There apears to be no vertical shift so we can conclude that $k=0$. Close inspections reveals a small horizontal shift of an estimated amount of $h=\frac{\pi}{24}$. The period is the horizontal distance from peak to peak which appears to be $p=\frac{3\pi}{2}$. Substituting these values into equation $(1)$ obtains

$$ y=\sin\left(\frac{4}{3}\left(x-\frac{\pi}{24}\right)\right)$$

which may be simplified to the form

$$ y=\sin\left(\frac{4}{3}x-\frac{\pi}{18}\right)$$

Comment: Very helpful! Thank you!

Comment: You are most welcome. There is an arrow to the left of the answer which the questioner can check to accept the best answer.

Comment: I have another graph that I can't seem to figure out. Would you mind taking a  look at it? I have posted it as a new question